# How to run a script when a notebook is loaded

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a set of notebooks that has some common start up script. I want to put this startup script(a somefile.py file) in the notebook folder, and when the notebook's kernel is started(or restarted), I want this script run in the kernel.

I know that I can put this file in the profile folder, but since I am working on the set of notebooks on a few PC, and I only want the script been run for the set of notebooks. A global startup script is not very good for this case.